# Iterate thru ec2 describe instance boto3

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to get specific values for a describe instance call. So for example, if I want to get the 'Hypervisor' value or the Ebs has 'DeleteOnTermintation' value from the output. Below is the current code I am currently using to make the call and iterate thru the dictionary output.

```
import boto3
import pprint
from datetime import datetime
import json

client = boto3.client('ec2')

filters = [{  
'Name': 'tag:Name',
'Values': ['*']
}]


class DatetimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime):
        return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    elif isinstance(obj, date):
        return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)    


output = json.dumps((client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)), cls=DatetimeEncoder)  

pprint.pprint(output)

for v in output:
  print v['Hypervisor']
```

Getting this error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Using the pprint to see all the values available from the output.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's how you could display the information via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, Hypervisor, NetworkInterfaces[0].Attachment.DeleteOnTermination]'
```

Here's some Python:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances()

for r in response['Reservations']:
  for i in r['Instances']:
    print i['InstanceId'], i['Hypervisor']
    for b in i['BlockDeviceMappings']:
      print b['Ebs']['DeleteOnTermination']
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's John's answer but updated for Python3

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances()

for r in response['Reservations']:
    for i in r['Instances']:
        print(i['InstanceId'], i['Hypervisor'])
        for b in i['BlockDeviceMappings']:
            print(b['Ebs']['DeleteOnTermination'])
```

Answer (score 7):

I know I am kinda late to the party, but my 2 cents for readability is to use generator comprehension (python 3):

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances()
block_mappings = (block_mapping
                  for reservation in response["Reservations"]
                  for instance in reservation["Instances"]
                  for block_mapping in instance["BlockDeviceMappings"])

for block_mapping in block_mappings:
  print(block_mapping["Ebs"]["DeleteOnTermination"])
```

You can also use `jmespath`, the same query engine behind awscli `--query` flag, to get the nested results automatically:

```py
import jmespath
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances()
print(jmespath.search(
    "Reservations[].Instances[].DeviceBlockMappings[].Ebs.DeleteOnTermination", 
    response
))
```

Or, in case you need more power, use `pyjq`. Its syntax is a little different from jmespath which is used in awscli, but it has more advantages over it. Let's say you want not only the `DeviceBlockMappings` but also to keep to which `InstanceId` it is related to. In `jmespath` you can't really do this, because there is no access to outer structures, just a single nested path. In `pyjq` you can do something like this:

```py
import pyjq
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances()
print(pyjq.all(
  "{id: .Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId, d:.Reservations[].Instances[].DeviceBlockMappings[]}",
  response
))
```

This will yield a list of device block mappings with their corresponding InstanceId, kind of like a mongo's unwind operation:

```js
{'id': string, d: {'Ebs': {'DeleteOnTermination': boolean}}}[]
```

Answer (score -2):

print (jmespath.search("Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId, SubnetId, ImageId, PrivateIpAddress, Tags[*]]", response))

Comment: This is really too little to be a useful answer. Please explain what your proposing here